# Switches implementation Help

Tags: switches, breadboard

I am an aspiring student taking a robotics course. 
 I currently have a problem about a circuit I am currently making. This circuit looks very similar to this one here: [image: circuit]

Falstad actual circuit: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Ag+544+208+576+208+0%0Ar+416+208+464+208+0+330%0A162+464+208+544+208+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ax+377+135+430+138+4+24+7432%0Ax+276+137+327+140+4+24+7411%0Ax+166+134+219+137+4+24+7438%0Aw+320+240+384+224+0%0Aw+320+176+384+192+0%0A152+384+208+416+208+0+2+0+5%0A150+288+240+320+240+0+3+0+5%0A150+288+176+320+176+0+3+0+5%0A151+176+240+224+240+0+2+0+5%0A151+176+176+224+176+0+2+0+5%0Av+64+208+96+208+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+64+208+48+208+0%0Aw+224+176+240+176+0%0Aw+240+176+240+160+0%0Aw+240+160+288+160+0%0Aw+240+176+272+176+0%0Aw+224+240+224+192+0%0Aw+224+192+288+192+0%0Aw+272+176+272+224+0%0Aw+272+224+288+224+0%0Aw+272+176+288+176+0%0Aw+256+336+256+256+0%0Aw+256+256+256+240+0%0Aw+256+240+288+240+0%0Aw+96+208+96+176+0%0Aw+176+176+176+160+0%0Aw+128+176+128+192+0%0Ar+128+176+128+128+0+10000%0Ag+128+128+128+112+0%0Aw+128+192+176+192+0%0Aw+128+176+176+176+0%0Aw+96+208+96+240+0%0Aw+128+240+128+224+0%0Aw+176+240+176+256+0%0Aw+128+224+176+224+0%0Aw+128+240+176+240+0%0Aw+128+336+256+336+0%0Ar+96+336+64+336+0+10000%0Ag+64+336+48+336+0%0Aw+256+256+288+256+0%0As+96+176+128+176+0+0+false%0As+96+240+128+240+0+0+false%0Aw+96+240+96+304+0%0Aw+96+304+96+336+0%0Ar+128+240+128+272+0+10000%0Ag+128+272+128+288+0%0As+96+336+128+336+0+0+false%0A

I built this circuit in real life and in simulation with no problems. It is when I add in the switches that things seem to change. Normally I just use wires to represent my inputs. (Example: wire in = 1, wire out = 0.) I completely built the circuit on a breadboard in real life and used wires for changing the inputs. It works completely fine and works as expected with this wire method. Based on this I would expect that I can just change my inputs real easy with some switches. This is were my problem is. When I implement these switches I come across various problems. Problems such as false logic and led staying off after certain inputs.

I have no idea what could be causing these problems, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please describe the desired behavior and what you're seeing. Also, a diagram using the built-in editor would be much more readable.

Comment: @Jaden. You have a serious error in your drawing. It shows the battery + connected to the 7438 gate inputs. If the real circuit is that way it will not work.

Comment: 7438???    I think you need to check the 6.3V filament voltage. Or you might be using the wrong type of coal to power them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using genuine archaic bipolar TTL parts, like a 7438 (with no letters after the "74") or other bipolar parts like 74LSxx, 74ALSxx, you must be aware that their inputs source current and will appear as a "High" or logic "1", unless pulled really hard to Ground.  The inputs must be pulled below 0.8 volts to appear as a "Low" or logic "0".  Since the inputs of a 7438 can source 1.6 mA, the required pull-down resistor is 500 Ohms or less - your 10K pull-downs are much to high a value to pull the inputs down to a "Low" level.

Traditionally, we would place a switch between the input pin and Ground, with a 5K or so pull-up resistor from the input pin to Vcc.

CMOS parts such as a 74HC38 (or most anything else with a "C" in the middle) have a very high input impedance, so a 10K pull-up or pull-down resistor will easily hold an input "High" or "Low".

Comment: OP made a mistake in the drawing or the actual circuit by feeding Vcc to the 7438 inputs. Your logic is good and correct +1.

Comment: @Sparky256 That's a switch = 5 V input.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of 7411 doesn't have a pull down. You've attached it across the power supply.